# How to bind two lists with same structure?

Tags: r, list, purrr

#### Introduction

I have two nested lists with the same structure that I'd like to combine (in the `c()` sense).

There might already exist a concept for what I mean by *same structure* in graph theory, or in computer science, for this relationship but I am not aware.

So here is my attempt to clarify what I mean by *same structure*:

- Elements of a list at some level are either all named or none is named;
- When we have named elements there are never duplicated names at that level;
- Parent-child node relationships are the same for the two lists, when the nodes are named elements themselves.

So I am wondering if there is already a solution for this problem which I feel might be rather general and common...(?) Any solution involving:

- Using base `rapply`;
- Tidyverse solution with some combination of `purrr` functions;
- Functions from the `rlist` package

would be great!

#### Example

`foo` and `bar` are two example lists with same structure.

`wonderful` is the desired list that results from combining `foo` and `bar` (done manually).

I hope it is clear enough!

```r
# Input lists: foo and bar
foo <- list(a = list(a1 = 1:3, a2 = rep('a', 3)), b = list(b1 = list(b11 = c(4,5,6), b12 = rep('b', 3)), b2 = list(b21 = list(b31 = c(0, 1, 2)))), c = list(list(c21 = 1:3), list(c21 = 4:6), list(c21 = 7:9)))
bar <- list(a = list(a1 = 1:3, a2 = rep('z', 3)), b = list(b1 = list(b11 = c(-1,2,5), b12 = rep('b', 3)), b2 = list(b21 = list(b31 = -c(1,2,3)))), c = list(list(c21 = 3:1), list(c21 = 5:3)))

# wonderful: desired list (result from combining foo and bar)
wonderful <- list(
  a = list(
    a1 = c(foo$a$a1, bar$a$a1), 
    a2 = c(foo$a$a2, bar$a$a2)
    ),
  b = list(
    b1 = list(
      b11 = c(foo$b$b1$b11, bar$b$b1$b11),
      b12 = c(foo$b$b1$b12, bar$b$b1$b12)
      ),
    b2 = list(
      b21 = list(
        b31 = c(foo$b$b2$b21$b31, bar$b$b2$b21$b31)
        )
      )
    ),
  c = c(foo$c, bar$c)
)

str(foo)
#> List of 3
#>  $ a:List of 2
#>   ..$ a1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   ..$ a2: chr [1:3] "a" "a" "a"
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ b11: num [1:3] 4 5 6
#>   .. ..$ b12: chr [1:3] "b" "b" "b"
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ b21:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ b31: num [1:3] 0 1 2
#>  $ c:List of 3
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 4 5 6
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 7 8 9

str(bar)
#> List of 3
#>  $ a:List of 2
#>   ..$ a1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   ..$ a2: chr [1:3] "z" "z" "z"
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ b11: num [1:3] -1 2 5
#>   .. ..$ b12: chr [1:3] "b" "b" "b"
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ b21:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ b31: num [1:3] -1 -2 -3
#>  $ c:List of 2
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 3 2 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 5 4 3

str(wonderful)
#> List of 3
#>  $ a:List of 2
#>   ..$ a1: int [1:6] 1 2 3 1 2 3
#>   ..$ a2: chr [1:6] "a" "a" "a" "z" ...
#>  $ b:List of 2
#>   ..$ b1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ b11: num [1:6] 4 5 6 -1 2 5
#>   .. ..$ b12: chr [1:6] "b" "b" "b" "b" ...
#>   ..$ b2:List of 1
#>   .. ..$ b21:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ b31: num [1:6] 0 1 2 -1 -2 -3
#>  $ c:List of 5
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 4 5 6
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 7 8 9
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 3 2 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ c21: int [1:3] 5 4 3
```

Comment: Recursive function comes to my mind... maybe read about `?stack`

Comment: @zx8754: Thanks! Going to take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a go at it:

```
library(purrr)

rec_map <- function(fizz, buzz) {
  if(is.atomic(fizz) | is.null(names(fizz))){
    c(fizz, buzz)
  } else {
    imap(fizz,
         ~rec_map(fizz[[.y]], buzz[[.y]]))
  }
}

temp <- rec_map(foo, bar)

all.equal(temp, wonderful)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I'm by no means a computer scientist, so take the solution with a grain of salt. I am not certain about the behavior desired when there are no names for one level, but then one level down there are names (e.g., `foo$c`). So I just combined the results (`c()`) if we encountered a level without names.

#### edit to take a number of lists:

```
prec_map <- function(...){
  dots <- list(...)
  first_el = dots[[1]]
  if(is.atomic(first_el) | is.null(names(first_el))){
    do.call(c, dots)
  } else {
    imap(first_el,
         function(el, nme){
           one_level_down <- map(dots, nme)
           do.call(prec_map, one_level_down)
         })
  }
}

temp <- prec_map(foo, bar)

all.equal(temp, wonderful)
[1] TRUE
```

I haven't tested it out thoroughly, but light testing looks like it gets the job done.

Comment: Wonderful! How you think I could change `rec_map` into `prec_map` as in `map` and `pmap`, i.e. a parallel version of `rec_map`?

Comment: @rmagno I intend to give this a look later today when I've some more time, sorry!

Comment: `prec_map` could be expressed as `function(.l) reduce(.l, rec_map)` or `partial(reduce, .f = rec_map)` or `. %>% reduce(rec_map)`, used as`prec_map(list(foo, bar))`

Comment: i like @Aurèle's suggestion in using reduce to handle more lists. I've taken a little more of a top down approach above (rather that side-to-side).

Comment: @zack: is the passed `buzz` in `imap(fizz, ~rec_map(fizz[[.y]], buzz[[.y]]), buzz)` doing anything?

Comment: it doesn't look like it, i thought it was taking buzz from the dots argument to `imap` but it was pulling it from the arguments passed to the `rec_map` function. I've edited it out now.

Comment: @zack: Nice, even simpler then. The `|` in `is.atomic(fizz) | is.null(names(fizz))` should be `||`, right? (though it won't make a difference in this case).

Comment: either works in this case. They'll amount to the same because `is.null` and `is.atomic` return length 1 logical vectors. I suppose if you want to ensure you haven't accidentally passed a > length 1 vector to the `if` statement, you'd use `|` (it will show a warning in this case). If you'd rather just not worry about it, `||` would work.

Answer (score 2):

`list_merge` does something close to the requirements:

```
library(purrr)

res <- list_merge(foo, !!! bar)

all.equal(wonderful, list_merge(foo, !!! bar))
# [1] "Component “c”: Length mismatch: comparison on first 3 components"       
# [2] "Component “c”: Component 1: Component 1: Numeric: lengths (3, 6) differ"
# [3] "Component “c”: Component 2: Component 1: Numeric: lengths (3, 6) differ"
```

The only difference seems to be for elements that are unnamed lists (e.g. `foo$c` and `bar$c`), the elements of which are concatenated by position (`foo$c[[1]]` with `bar$c[[1]]`, `foo$c[[2]]` with `bar$c[[2]]`, and `foo$c[[3]]` left alone since there is no `bar$c[[3]]`... rather than `c(foo$c, bar$c)`).

---

And a parallel version could be:

```
plist_merge <- function(.l) {
  reduce(.l, ~ list_merge(.x, !!! .y))
}

all.equal(
  plist_merge(list(foo, bar)),
  list_merge(foo, !!! bar)
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's a neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit more about this problem in general... and after some inspiration from dplyr's joins, here's three joins for lists for my own future reference:

- `lst_left_join`
- `lst_right_join`
- `lst_inner_join`

```r
library(purrr)

#
# Inspired by dplyr's joins: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#inner-join
# Here's some (more or less equivalent) list joins
# 
lst_left_join <- function(lst_x, lst_y) {
  if(is.atomic(lst_x) || is.null(names(lst_x))){
    c(lst_x, lst_y)
  } else {
    imap(lst_x, ~lst_left_join(lst_x[[.y]], lst_y[[.y]]))
  }
}

plst_left_join <- function(.l) reduce(.l, lst_left_join)

lst_right_join <- function(lst_x, lst_y) {
  if(is.atomic(lst_y) || is.null(names(lst_y))){
    c(lst_x, lst_y)
  } else {
    imap(lst_y, ~lst_right_join(lst_x[[.y]], lst_y[[.y]]))
  }
}

plst_right_join <- function(.l) reduce(.l, lst_right_join)

lst_inner_join <- function(lst_x, lst_y) {
  if(is.atomic(lst_y) || is.null(names(lst_y))){
    c(lst_x, lst_y)
  } else {
    common_names <- intersect(names(lst_x), names(lst_y))
    names(common_names) <- common_names # so that map preserves names
    map(common_names, ~lst_inner_join(lst_x[[.x]], lst_y[[.x]]))
  }
}
plst_inner_join <- function(.l) reduce(.l, lst_inner_join)

# Input lists: foo and bar.
foo <- list(x1 = 1:2, x3 = 30+5:6)
bar <- list(x1 = 10+1:2, x2 = 10+3:4)

# Output lists: r1, r2 and r3.
r1 <- lst_left_join(foo, bar)
r2 <- lst_right_join(foo, bar)
r3 <- lst_inner_join(foo, bar)

str(r1)
#> List of 2
#>  $ x1: num [1:4] 1 2 11 12
#>  $ x3: num [1:2] 35 36
str(r2)
#> List of 2
#>  $ x1: num [1:4] 1 2 11 12
#>  $ x2: num [1:2] 13 14
str(r3)
#> List of 1
#>  $ x1: num [1:4] 1 2 11 12
```